# Which services should be stopped by preinst vs. prerm scripts?

Tags: debian, deb

The debian manual (https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-maintscripts) says the following about `preinst`:

> Many 'preinst' scripts stop services for packages which are being upgraded until their installation or upgrade is completed

And this about `prerm`:

> This script typically stops any daemons which are associated with a package.

As far as I understand, an upgrade will call both `prerm` of the old package and `preinst` of the new one, and when removing a package only `prerm` will be called.

So, if I create a debian package which contains a service, is there any good reason to prefer using `preinst` over `prerm`? Or do I need both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The document you linked to is the FAQ, which, while relevant, isn't necessarily regarded as authoritative (the distinctions are probably subtle though and any inconsistency is really a bug). The authoritative document is the Debian Policy Manual, which has a [whole chapter dedicated to maintainer scripts](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html). Because that's not all that easy to read, there are [helpful diagrams on the wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts) which explain the relationships between the maintainer scripts.

Basically, the only script which **needs** to stop services in the matching package is `prerm`; as you point out this script is called when removing the package as well as when upgrading it. An important point in some cases is that it's the `prerm` script of the installed package which is used by default; if it fails before an upgrade though, the packaging system will try the upgraded `prerm` script too.

`preinst` always comes after `prerm` during an upgrade, and by the time it's run the services are supposed to be stopped. Some packages' `preinst` scripts do try to stop the services again, just to be sure; examples of this include [`mysql-server-5.6`](https://tracker.debian.org/mysql-server-5.6) and [`timidity`](https://tracker.debian.org/timidity), but there aren't many.

So in summary, you must stop your services in `prerm`, and you may do so in `preinst` too (although there's no need effectively); you mustn't prefer `preinst` over `prerm` for this, and you don't need both. I'd just use `prerm`.

(Strictly speaking, I should clarify that the Policy Manual is descriptive rather than prescriptive, in that it documents current practice rather than defining it — so it's not as authoritative as you might expect, and practices do evolve before they're documented there. But in this particular case Policy is accurate. While I'm at it, since `prerm` knows whether it's being called for an upgrade, it may be tempting to try clever tricks and leave services running until some later script can restart them, in order to reduce service downtime; but that's just asking for trouble.)

Comment: +1. re: your last paragraph.  Some packages don't `stop` and then `start` the service, they just `restart` or `reload` the service later in the `postinst`.  Whether that's a good thing to do or not depends on the service itself.  For some it works perfectly and is exactly the Right Thing to do.  For others, it may be "asking for trouble" as you say.

Comment: Note I did say "until some later script can *restart* them" ;-). The hard part is that deciding this now has consequences on future versions of the package: if the current `prerm` doesn't stop the service on upgrades, all future `postinst`s (up to at least the last security update to the next stable release) need to handle the restart. In some cases it is the right thing to do, but for beginner packagers I'd still recommend stopping the service in `prerm` only.

Comment: Also, `reload` is nice but probably never the right thing to do on a package upgrade — in particular, the upgrade may be happening because of a security fix, and if that's indirectly via a binNMU for a library update, the package maintainer won't get a chance to handle it explicitly in `postinst`.

Comment: You're right about reload, i didn't think that through. it makes no sense not to restart if the program binary has changed.  Delaying restart, though, can be hugely beneficial.  It can mean the difference between a few seconds downtime for a service, or 10+ minutes (or even hours if the dist-upgrade is waiting on an answer to a question...about what to do with a completely unrelated package's conffile...while the sysadmin's gone off to do something more urgent. like sleep :)